# Can't Publish Another App on PlayStore

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just finished an app with Ionic Framework and when I tried to upload for the **2nd time** my app, after Google ask for corrections, I'm getting this error:

**Use another code version for your app...**

I've searched in a lot of places including here on Stackoverflow, but coudn't solve the issue.

I'm using crosswalk with Ionic. And here's my files for reference: 
(Now, after a lot of changes... :/)

Was I who changed to company and appname ok :D

***config.xml***

**ORIGINAL VALUE**

```
<widgeT
      id="br.com.company.appname" 
      version="0.0.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
```

**NOW**

```
<widget 
      id="br.com.company.appname" 
      version="2.2.2"
      versionCode="100" 
      android-versionCode="100" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
      xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

***build.gradle***

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 100
        versionName "2.2"
        //versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        //versionCode 17
        //applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        //if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        //    minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        //}
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }
```

The commented code above is the original.

***AndroidManifest.xml*** (wich I can't alter, just for reference)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="100" android:versionName="2.2.2" package="br.com.company.appname" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I build the release app with theses commands:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore appname.keystore appname-armv7-release-unsigned.apk appname

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore appname.keystore appname-x86-release-unsigned.apk appname

C:\android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign -v 4 appname-armv7-release-unsigned.apk appname_armv7.apk

C:\android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign -v 4 appname-x86-release-unsigned.apk appname_x86.apk
```

I build the armv7 and x86 arch. And both are on Gooogle.

The armv7 is on version 12
The x86 is on version 14

And no matter what changes I make on the files above, the Google still says the code version has to be different from 12 / 14....

Comment: increment the version code as well as version name, it should be good. Whenever you want to update your app, the VersionCode and VersionName should be incremented to be accepted by developer console to update.

Comment: @AkshayBhat
I always update both :/
I did about 20-30 builds.... spent a day uploading and get rejected..

Comment: have you checked your manifest file, better to update there as well

Comment: @AkshayBhat 
I finally dscover MY MISTAKE XD

I was generating a regular build :: 
`ionic build android`

Not an **release** build...
`cordova build --release android`

So my changes never work.

Anyway thx, your answer forced to think outside the box :D o/

Comment: Opps. I forgot to tell the basic thing that is release build :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set proper version and version code name

Example First Release
versionCode 1
versionName "0.1"

Second Release
versionCode 2
versionName "1.0"